# iptables does not generates log

Tags: debian, iptables, syslog

I have this script `make_firewall.sh` with rules for iptables:

```
iptables -F    
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 80 -j ACCEPT
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 443 -j ACCEPT
iptables -A INPUT -s 127.0.0.1 -d 127.0.0.1 -j ACCEPT
iptables -A OUTPUT -p tcp --dport 80 -m state --state NEW -j ACCEPT 
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --sport 80 -m state --state ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp -j LOG --log-level info --log-prefix='[netfilter] '
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp -j LOG --log-prefix='[netfilter] '
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp -j DROP
```

And I have this at `/etc/rsyslog.d/my_iptables.conf` :

```
:msg,contains,"[netfilter] " /var/log/iptables.log
```

And too this at `/etc/rsyslog.conf` :

```
#  /etc/rsyslog.conf    Configuration file for rsyslog.
#
#                       For more information see
#                       /usr/share/doc/rsyslog-doc/html/rsyslog_conf.html


#################
#### MODULES ####
#################

$ModLoad imuxsock # provides support for local system logging
#$ModLoad imklog   # provides kernel logging support
#$ModLoad immark  # provides --MARK-- message capability

# provides UDP syslog reception
#$ModLoad imudp
#$UDPServerRun 514

# provides TCP syslog reception
#$ModLoad imtcp
#$InputTCPServerRun 514


###########################
#### GLOBAL DIRECTIVES ####
###########################

#
# Use traditional timestamp format.
# To enable high precision timestamps, comment out the following line.
#
$ActionFileDefaultTemplate RSYSLOG_TraditionalFileFormat

#
# Set the default permissions for all log files.
#
$FileOwner root
$FileGroup adm
$FileCreateMode 0640
$DirCreateMode 0755
$Umask 0022

#
# Where to place spool and state files
#
$WorkDirectory /var/spool/rsyslog

#
# Include all config files in /etc/rsyslog.d/
#
$IncludeConfig /etc/rsyslog.d/*.conf


###############
#### RULES ####
###############

#
# First some standard log files.  Log by facility.
#
auth,authpriv.*          -/var/log/auth.log
*.*;auth,authpriv.none          -/var/log/syslog
cron.*                   -/var/log/cron.log
daemon.*                        -/var/log/daemon.log
kern.*                          -/var/log/kern.log
lpr.*                           -/var/log/lpr.log
mail.*                          -/var/log/mail.log
user.*                          -/var/log/user.log

#
# Logging for the mail system.  Split it up so that
# it is easy to write scripts to parse these files.
#
mail.info                       -/var/log/mail.info
mail.warn                       -/var/log/mail.warn
mail.err                 -/var/log/mail.err

#
# Logging for INN news system.
#
news.crit                -/var/log/news/news.crit
news.err                 -/var/log/news/news.err
news.notice                     -/var/log/news/news.notice

#
# Some "catch-all" log files.
#
*.=debug;\
        auth,authpriv.none;\
        news.none;mail.none     -/var/log/debug
*.=info;*.=notice;*.=warn;\
        auth,authpriv.none;\
        cron,daemon.none;\
        mail,news.none          -/var/log/messages

#
# Emergencies are sent to everybody logged in.
#
*.emerg                         :omusrmsg:*

#
# I like to have messages displayed on the console, but only on a virtual
# console I usually leave idle.
#
#daemon,mail.*;\
#       news.=crit;news.=err;news.=notice;\
#       *.=debug;*.=info;\
#       *.=notice;*.=warn       /dev/tty8

# The named pipe /dev/xconsole is for the `xconsole' utility.  To use it,
# you must invoke `xconsole' with the `-file' option:
#
#    $ xconsole -file /dev/xconsole [...]
#
# NOTE: adjust the list below, or you'll go crazy if you have a reasonably
#      busy site..
#
daemon.*;mail.*;\
        news.err;\
        *.=debug;*.=info;\
        *.=notice;*.=warn       |/dev/xconsole
```

The content of the folder `/var/log` is (I checked all files on this folder, but I not found nothing from iptables):

```
-rw-r--r--  1 root        root    1593 Jul  1 17:09 alternatives.log
drwxr-x---  2 root        adm     4096 Jul  2 10:13 apache2
drwxr-xr-x  2 root        root    4096 Jun 20 16:49 apt
-rw-r-----  1 root        adm  4490518 Jul 14 22:58 auth.log
-rw-------  1 root        utmp  495361 Jul 14 19:44 btmp
-rw-r-----  1 root        adm   180921 Jul 14 20:06 daemon.log
-rw-r-----  1 root        adm      775 Jun 20 16:59 debug
-rw-r-----  1 root        adm        1 Nov  9  2015 dmesg
-rw-r--r--  1 root        root  132769 Jul 14 20:04 dpkg.log
drwxr-s---  2 Debian-exim adm     4096 Jul  1 17:09 exim4
-rw-r-----  1 root        adm     4363 Jul 14 19:43 fail2ban.log
-rw-r--r--  1 root        root    3424 Jul  1 17:09 faillog
drwxr-xr-x  2 root        root    4096 Nov  9  2015 fsck
-rw-rw-r--  1 root        utmp   31244 Jul 14 19:44 lastlog
-rw-r-----  1 root        adm     3748 Jul 14 20:06 messages
drwxr-s---  2 mysql       adm     4096 Jun 20 17:03 mysql
-rw-r-----  1 mysql       adm        0 Jun 20 17:03 mysql.err
-rw-r-----  1 mysql       adm        0 Jun 20 17:03 mysql.log
-rw-r-----  1 root        adm  2628602 Jul 14 22:58 syslog
-rw-rw-r--  1 root        utmp   40704 Jul 14 19:44 wtmp
```

I'm using: Debian 8 (jessie) with iptables v1.4.21

**My question is: why iptables does not generates any log?**

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Have you tried a simple tutorial such as http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2012/08/iptables-log-packets/?utm_source=feedburner ?

Answer (score 0):

I find that `rsyslog` won't create custom log files initially, so I do it myself.
Note: permissions are - as always - important! - make sure rsyslog has perms to write to the new log file, try something like

```
print_status "Give Iptables its own log file - instead of /var/log/syslog"


sudo touch /var/log/iptables.log
 # assign appropriate ownership to your setup
sudo chown -v root:adm /var/log/iptables.log
sudo chmod -v 660 /var/log/iptables.log
```

then obviously you need to restart `rsyslog` for the changes to take effect

```
sudo service rsyslog restart
```

or whatever command you use on your distro, possibly?

```
sudo /etc/init.d/rsyslog restart
```

Comment: syslog user does not exists! #chown -v syslog:adm /var/log/iptables.log
chown: invalid user: 'syslog:adm'        ......... I'm using root:adm for iptables.log

Comment: @AllanAndrade yes, thats why I added the comment *# assign appropriate ownership to your setup*. you need to assign perms to the file, such that `rsyslog` can write to it. so see what rsyslog runs as - `ps -efl | grep rsyslog` then use that account

Comment: Ths syslogfile: -rw-r-----  1 root        adm  2642416 Jul 14 23:52 syslog
........... and I put the same for -rw-------  1 root        adm        1 Jul 14 23:29 iptables.log

Comment: @AllanAndrade ok, I've updated my answer, please recreate the file `/var/log/iptables.log` using the commands I gave, then restart the `rsyslog` daemon.

Comment: @AllanAndrade:  Please let us know if that solves it.

Comment: @the_velour_fog I executed the codes, and tryed the firewall but iptables still empty.

Comment: Maybe anything that I need to install? I'm using a very minimal version.

Comment: your iptables config looks ok. how are you testing your firewall. you will need to try make a cknnection that wont be matched by you webserver rules so your log rules get matched before you drop the packets

Comment: I'm testing with: http://www.yougetsignal.com/tools/open-ports/ using port 22 and too with: http://www.ipfingerprints.com/portscan.php

Comment: @AllanAndrade:  This is why I asked you to try a simple tutorial to see if following it solved your problem because I think there's a mistake in your rules but I can't test them out right now.